# writing lists to text file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to read from 3 txt files and merge them into one big txt file.

Ex text file1:

```
John
Mary
Joe
```

Ex text file2:

```
Alabama
Alaska
Michigan
```

Ex text file3:

```
Maybe
Attending
Not Attending
```

I'm not sure what else to add to my code

```
path = '/home/pi/Documents/Test/name.txt'
file1 = open (path, 'r')
name = file1.read()

statepath = '/home/pi/Documents/Test/state.txt'
file2 = open (path, 'r')
states = file2.read()

statuspath = '/home/pi/Documents/Test/status.txt'
file3 = open(statuspath, 'r')
status = file3.read()

finalpath = '/home/pi/Documents/Test/final.txt'
file4 = open(finalpath, 'w')
final = file4.read()


for item in name, states, status:
    final.write(file1, "\n")
    final.write(file2, "\n")
    final.write(file3, "\n")

file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
final.close()
```

final expected output of the file is

```
John  <------- first value in file1
Alabama <------ first value in file2
Maybe  <------- first value in file 3
Mary  <---------- second value in file 1
Alaska
Attending
Joe
Michigan
Not Attending
```

Basically trying to loop through all of them and print them sequentially 
not sure how to loop.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: didnt notice that , i just added to it.. not sure how to loop through the lists to write them all to a file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are writing in final without actually ever reading anything so it can't work.  Replace `file1`, `file2`, `file3` with the variables that have the `read()` attribute.

---

Just use a `for` statement with each variable you want to loop. Like this:

```
for i in name:
    for j in states:
        for k in status:
            all = i + '\n` + j + '\n' + k + '\n' 

final.write(all)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution, but you should be sure that you have the same length of 3 files.

```
def main():
    name_path = 'name.txt'
    state_path = 'state.txt'
    status_path = 'status.txt'
    final_path = 'final.txt'
    with open(name_path, 'r') as file1, open(state_path, 'r') as file2, open(status_path, 'r') as file3, open(final_path, 'w') as final:
        for line in file1.readlines():
            final.write(line)
            final.write(file2.readline())
            final.write(file3.readline())
```

Comment: i tried using this and it seems to stop after 4 loops... i have 900 lines in each file.

Comment: @ClaudeSAugilar are you sure? I just rechecked it and it works. However try to use another version that I posted, it's more readable and pythonic

Comment: you're welcome, you can mark the right answer that helped you, for other people to see working answer

Answer (score 0):

Some way of doing this for a general case, using itertools:

```
import itertools as it
files = [
    '/home/pi/Documents/Test/name.txt',
    '/home/pi/Documents/Test/state.txt',
    '/home/pi/Documents/Test/status.txt'
]

def loadData(fpath):
    with open(fpath, "r") as f:
        yield from f.redlines()

with open('/home/pi/Documents/Test/final.txt') as f:
    for e in it.chain.from_iterable(zip(*map(loadDAta, files))):
        f.write(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just slightly improved `Netwave` version and it seems to be the right pythonic way to solver this task, the full code will be something like this

```
import itertools as it


def load_data(fpath):
    with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            yield line


def main():
    files = [
        '/home/pi/Documents/Test/name.txt',
        '/home/pi/Documents/Test/state.txt',
        '/home/pi/Documents/Test/status.txt'
    ]

    with open('/home/pi/Documents/Test/final.txt', 'w') as f:
        for e in it.chain.from_iterable(zip(*map(load_data, files))):
            for line in e:
                f.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```